# shelve object and python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, shelve

I am not sure this is a bug of the shelve object,
but it is still quite odd behavior.
If you store a dictionnary object in a shelve object, it seems that you cannot modify easely the associated dictionnary.
Here is a python code to demonstrate:

```
>>> import shelve
>>> d=shelve.open('test')
>>> d['test'] = {'test1':'A' }
>>> print d['test']['test1']
A
>>> d['test']['test1'] = 'C'
>>> print d['test']['test1']
A # !!! odd
>>> d['test'] = {'test1':'A' }
>>> d1 = d['test']
>>> d1['test1'] = 'C'
>>> print d1
{'test1': 'C'}
>>> d['test']= d1
>>> print d['test']['test1']
C
>>> d['test'] = {'test1':'A' }
>>> d['test'] = {'test1':'C' }
>>> print d['test']['test1']
C
```

Is it normal behavior of the shelve object in python?

Comment: This is purely a python dictionary concept.. Nothing to do with shelve. Please learn dictionaries first.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation,

> ```
>       d[key] = data   # store data at key (overwrites old data if
>                       # using an existing key)
>
>       data = d[key]   # retrieve a COPY of the data at key (raise
>                       # KeyError if no such key) -- NOTE that this
>                       # access returns a *copy* of the entry!
> ```

So in your code, `d['test']= d1` will modify the original data, but `d['test']['test1'] = 'C'` will modify the new copied object. Use `d = shelve.open('test', writeback=True)` to modify this default and check the documentation for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

*Hopefully a better explanation*:

The Python [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module is a **Key/Value** store.

This essentially means it acts like a Python dictionary
(*which it does*). However when you do:

```
from shelve import open

d = open("test.db")
d["a"] = {"b": 1}
```

You are storing the following:

- key: `"a"`
- value: `{"b": 1}`

WHen you then ask the "store" for the key `a`
you immediately get back the value `{"b": 1}`
which is now a new object reference (`dict`)
in memory.

So the following would not store or make any
changes to the value stored in the store:

```
d["a"]["b"] = 2
```

This will only make changes to the "in-memory"
dict `{"b": 1}` which you are referencing
implicitly.

To store a new value for `{"b": 1}`  inside the key `a`
you must "explicitly" set a new key for `a` like so:

```
d["a"] = {"b": 2}
```